# Is it possible to use Scripting Bridge to open an app, but move it to the background?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to open the app Spotify, and move it to the background. I can easily open Spotify with

```
SpotifyApplication *Spotify = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.spotify.client"];
[Spotify activate];
```

But Spotify goes to the foreground, covering my windows. With iTunes, I can use

```
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
[iTunes run];
```

However it's an iTunes specific method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you be willing to use `NSAppleScript` to do it?

```
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc]
    initWithSource:@"tell app \"Spotify\" to launch"];
NSDictionary *errorInfo;
[script executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
if (errorInfo) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", errorInfo);
}
```

You have to use the application name, not its bundle ID.